# Python:How to do operations on a grid

Tags: python-2.7

For a word game(something similar to image provided),where inside a grid various letters are entered on different tile,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Bmj.jpg) I had to create a 6*6 grid and then do operations on it like:

```
a)place the tile on a specific location in the grid and 
b)return the location of any tile on the grid
c)determining the top scoring words in the grid
```

Till now I have managed to create the grid but i have no clue of how to place a tile on a specific grid or fetch the location of a tile on the grid.I have created the following grid:

```
grid = [[" _" for x in range(6)]]
    for y in range(6):
        list1 = []
        for x in range(13):
            if x%2 == 0:
                 list1.append("|")
            else:
                 list1.append("_")
        grid.append(list1)

    for row in grid:
        print("".join(row))
```

I am new to python and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Did you try to run this piece of code? I don't think so because the indentation here is bad, so it won't work.

  - You should rename your variable `list1` to `row` for comprehension
    purpose : your variable names should always be as descriptive as
    possible.

Here to initialize in a more compact way your `grid` you could do:

```
    grid = [["_" if x%2==0 else "|" for x in range(13)] for x in range(6)]
```

To access a specific tile you can do:

```
    grid[y][x]
```

In example, the following command would print the cell on the third row second column:

```
    print(grid[3][2])
```

To set the value you can do:

```
     grid[y][x] = value
```

But I think that you should see a course about learning Python before trying to do these things.

Google it and good luck!

Comment: Thanks,I have corrected the code snippet that i had provided above and yes it was working.I was however unable to insert elements in the  grid using the way suggested by you.